# mongoose array push without duplicate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I use the following `update` command to model:

```
Room.update({_id: roomId, status: 'live'}, {$push: {"users" : {_id: user._id, loginName: user.loginName}}}, {}, function(err, room) {
```

model:

```
{
    _id: "56c0d9e332f6ddc80ec7271c",
    name: "Reqqqq2",
    creator: "MegaDaddgy",
    status: "live",
    __v: 0,
    users: [
        {
        _id: "56c0a986eeb118741109a45f",
        loginName: "MegaDaddgy"
        },
        {
        _id: "56bf96f56a0c220812f055e6",
        loginName: "Maad"
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't want to add duplicate fields to `users`, How can I do this?

Comment: Presumably you are following the convention of `_id` being "unique" so: `Room.update({ "_id": roomId, "status": "live", "users._id": { "$ne": user._id } }, { "$push": { "users": { "_id": user._id, "loginName": user.name } } })`. So basically looking for where the users `_id` is not present ( `$ne` is not equal to ). Not to hard is it now.

Answer (score 9):

The [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) could prevent the duplicate entry present in the `users`

```
Room.update(
   {_id: roomId, status: 'live'}, 
   {$addToSet: 
      {"users" : {_id: user._id, loginName: user.loginName}}}, function(err, room) {
```

Another way could be done through `$ne` same as Blakes mentioned in the comment as below

```
Room.update({ "_id": roomId, "status": "live", "users._id": { "$ne": user._id } }, { "$push": { "users": { "_id": user._id, "loginName": user.name } } })
```